# Erlang: rebar3 release, start beam first?

Tags: docker, erlang

I am trying to utilize a new feature in 19.3 per this question: [Erlang: does the application behavior trap SIGTERM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912781/erlang-does-the-application-behavior-trap-sigterm)

My understanding is that sending SIGTERM to BEAM now triggers a graceful shutdown in Erlang 19.3+

I start my application in Docker using the ENTRYPOINT `./_build/default/rel/myapp/bin/myapp` where `./_build/default/rel/myapp/bin/myapp` is generated from `rebar3 release`

When I do this in Docker, `myapp` gets PID1 and BEAM seems to gets another PID.

Is there a *different* set of commands I can run such that BEAM gets PID1 and myapp gets loaded from there? Something like

`./start_beam; ./start_my_app_via_beam`?

I need this because `docker stop` sends SIGTERM to the PID1. I need that to be BEAM. Using the above entrypoint, here is what happens in the container":

`top
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    1 root      20   0    4340    644    556 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 myapp
   14 root      20   0 3751188  50812   6660 S   0.0  0.6   0:00.48 beam.smp
   18 root      20   0   11492    116      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 epmd
   31 root      20   0    4220    680    604 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.10 erl_child_setup
   53 root      20   0   11456    944    840 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 inet_gethost
   54 root      20   0   17764   1660   1504 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 inet_gethost
   55 root      20   0   20252   3208   2720 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 bash
   61 root      20   0   21956   2468   2052 R   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 top`

Comment: I suspect that the `myapp` script starts the Erlang VM in the background, using the `run_erl` helper program. Perhaps it has some option to start the Erlang VM in the foreground? That should give it PID 1, I guess.

Comment: @legoscia this release is generated using rebar3 with `rebar3 release` if that helps. THe script `./_build/default/rel/myapp/bin/myapp` is complicated...

Answer (score 0):

Currently, to get around this, I have this horrendous beast:

````
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "if testing locally send SIGTERM to $$"

term_handler() {
  echo "Stopping the Erlang VM gracefully"
  #/usr/local/Cellar/erlang/19.1/lib/erlang/lib/erl_interface-
3.9.1/bin/erl_call -c myapp -s -a 'init stop' -n 'myapp@localhost'
  /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/erl_interface-3.9.2/bin/erl_call -c myapp -s -a 'init stop' -n 'myapp@localhost'
  echo "Erlang VM Stopped"
}

trap term_handler SIGQUIT SIGINT SIGTERM

./_build/default/rel/myapp/bin/myapp & 
PID=$!

echo "Erlang VM Started"
#wait $PID
while kill -0 $PID ; do wait $PID ; EXIT_STATUS=$? ; done
echo "Exiting Wrapper."
exit $EXIT_STATUS
```

And then I do `ENTRYPOINT : ["./thisscript"]`
````

This beast becomes PID 1, and it finds the correct thing to kill after that.

I'm trying to get rid of this script.